# I've got a error message on the manifest.json file

Tags: json

I've been working on this manifest.json file and I got this error. I don't know what to do. I should be very happy if somebody can explain what should I do to fix it, please.[image: Error Log]

When you want to see the picture of code(error message)just click on the text and you are gonna be able to see it. Thank you so much.[[image: Slightly more context.]

Comment: When you want to see the picture of code(error message) just click on text

Comment: I've submitted an edit which makes your images actual images instead of links. For future reference, you should only post images if they must be images, code should be transposed into real code format. Additionally, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for advice on how to write a good question. Including code that runs is a good start. Additionally, syntax errors are typically easy-to-fix. In this case, it seems like your "version" is missing a comma.

Comment: Thank you so much Delioth, that is very nice of you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after

```
"version": "0.0.1"
```

Comment: Ohh! You have right, Thank you so much Pat. You made me happy. Thank you :D